# How to set Folder as Parameter in PyQGIS script?

Tags: pyqgis, parameters

I know how to set the parameter of a folder but, not sure if I am using the right class.  
I want a user to select a folder which has items inside it, to be used for processing.
 
When I use self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination(self.INPUT3, self.tr("Folder location")))
This input looks like the folder is used to save the contents from the processing. Like in the input it says [Save to temporary folder] and when you click the “…” it says “Save to temporary Directory” and “Save to Directory..”  This is confusing for someone using this tool.
Is there not a simple blank input with the folder button at the end of it and then the user can set location.
 
See image.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use [QgsProcessingParameterFile](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingParameterFile.html#a9c78d9cc7ae1bd44ea5ce6773a70ebaa) and set the [behavior](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingParameterFile.html#a6a3f3ee2d7482fd374584b5b7fb884ff) to specify an input folder instead of a single file like this:

```py
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFile(
        self.INPUT,
        self.tr("Input folder"),
        behavior=QgsProcessingParameterFile.Folder))
```

Below is a very basic example script which simply returns the path to the input folder selected. Based on the template from Anita Graser's blog [here](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/).

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsProcessingParameterFile)
from qgis import processing
                    
                    
class ExAlgo(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
    def name(self):
        return "exalgo"
     
    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("exalgo", text)
         
    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr("Example script")
 
    def group(self):
        return self.tr("Examples")
 
    def groupId(self):
        return "examples"
 
    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example script with an input folder")
 
    def helpUrl(self):
        return "https://qgis.org"
         
    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()
   
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFile(
            self.INPUT,
            self.tr("Input folder"),
            behavior=QgsProcessingParameterFile.Folder))

 
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        source_folder_path = self.parameterAsFile(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
        return {'Input folder path': source_folder_path} # all processing algs must return a dictionary object (can be empty)
```